# How are Azure TSI Aggregate data types calculated?

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

I'm using Time Series Insights preview in Azure, to visualize data.  Some of our data is of the Aggregate type, using the COUNT operation (the only option).  My question is, does this count the items in the given time interval?  For example, if our data is coming once every 5 seconds, I would expect the aggregate value on the chart to be 1, for an interval of 5 seconds, which it is.  However, if I change the interval on the chart UI to 30 seconds, I would expect it to be something like 6, but it's still showing 1 on the chart.  Similarly, if we have 2 items per 5 seconds, it always shows 2, regardless of the time interval.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Randy to help troubleshoot, are you using TSI [Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-ux-panels) or [Gen1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-explorer) ?

Comment: Preview = Gen 2 I assume

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please so I can go to the same dashboard and try to reproduce this? Thanks

Comment: @asergaz, thanks for your comment.  After looking more deeply, it appears it is behaving correctly.  I wasn't zooming out enough to capture multiple events per interval.